# Yii2 submit link with Ajax

Tags: ajax, yii2

I'm trying to create votes for my content in Yii2, so I'm trying to insert data with Ajax using "a" tag and widget but with ajax it's not working , without ajax it's working perfect. but when I use Ajax it's not working and I have no errors in console.
my code for view is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#btn-vote-up' + <?= $pst_id ?>).on("click", function(e){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {"value" : "Like"},
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log (<?= $pst_id ?>);
                    $('#note-up' + <?= $pst_id ?>).load(' #note-up' + <?= $pst_id ?>);
                }               
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>


    <?= Html::a('<i class="ly-ic-favorite-plus"></i>', '#', [
                'class' => 'btn-logout',
                'id' => 'btn-vote-up'.$pst_id,
                'data'  => [
                    'params' => [
                        'value' => 'Like',
                        'pstIDL' => $pst_id,
                        ],
                    ],
        ]) ;
    ?>
    <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'note-up'.$pst_id]) ?>
        <span><?= $total_up ?></span>
    <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
```

And my widget code is :

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post('value') == 'Like')
            {
                $pstIDL = Yii::$app->request->post('pstIDL');

                $modelLIKEPOST = $this->findLikePost($pstIDL);

                AxVotePost::VoteUP($modelLIKEPOST, $this->usr_rid, $this->chn_id, $pstIDL);
                header('Location: ' .Url::current() );
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: saying it not working is not enough, what happens, when you send an ajax call, do you receive a 404 bad request or anything? and above all you are not sending the `$pstIDL` value when making an ajax call and only `value` is being sent.

Comment: I don't get any error no thing happen

Comment: the answer help me; thank you so much for your time this is the 3rd question you try to help me; thank you so much

Comment: :) we are all here to help each other @Bynd , you are always welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending the `$pstIDL` value when making an ajax call and only `value` is being sent, you can use `var data=$(this).data('params')` to get both `pstIDL`, and the `value` `json` and send it along the data in the call see below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#btn-vote-up' + <?= $pst_id ?>).on("click", function(e){
           var data= $(this).data('params');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: function(msg) {
                    console.log (<?= $pst_id ?>);
                    $('#note-up' + <?= $pst_id ?>).load(' #note-up' + <?= $pst_id ?>);
                }               
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but still not working; console.log pstIDL it's give "undefined".

Comment: I changed you code from var pstIDL=$(this).data('pstIDL'); to : var pstIDL = $(this).data('params'); and it's working; please can you edit your answer and change only var pstIDL=$(this).data('pstIDL'); to : var pstIDL = $(this).data('params');

Comment: yeah you can do it that way to get the whole json string and send as is @Bynd